# Standalone Java to dequeue JMS messages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

Can any one provide sample program to dequeue messages in Java? I want standalone java program which will do this task.

Lets say Oracle ha enqueued messages using `JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE` a payload type in queue "`myqueue`" whose owner is "`myowner`" & now I want to dequeue these messages using Java. Can any one provide sample program in stand alone Java?

Thanks!

---

@Ratha, I tried your sample & I can browse through all the messages & it works perfect!

However, when I try to consume those messages, I thought they'll get removed from the queue & display it to me through below line:

```
 System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED " + msg.getText());
```

But instead, it gives me error on below line:

```
 MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.createConsumer(Ljavax/jms/Destination;)Ljavax/jms/MessageConsumer;
at OracleAQClient.consumeMessage(OracleAQClient.java:141)
at OracleAQClient.main(OracleAQClient.java:159)
```

Can you please help me how to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to delete messages from a queue in the jmx-console.

Comment: @ Mike: Here you will not get the entire program. Just explain of whatever you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right  vendor specific or vendor neutral code..
To dequeue the message, use following code block

```
 public static void consumeMessage(String user, String queueName) {  
  Queue queue;
  try {
   QueueConnection QCon = getConnection();  
   Session session = QCon.createQueueSession(false,Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   QCon.start();
   queue = ((AQjmsSession) session).getQueue(user, queueName);
   MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
   TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
   System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED " + msg.getText());

   consumer.close();
   session.close();
   QCon.close();
  } catch (JMSException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

I have written, these posts, which contain more detail code;

http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/10/creating-queue-in-oracleaq.html

http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/10/java-client-for-jndi-lookup-with-ojms.html

Comment: Answers which simply link to other sites are not good answers.